# Rotating lighting environment content ARKit and SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, light

I come from Unity world. In Unity we can easily rotate the background skybox for `image based lighting`. I see that in Swift we can apply skybox by typing:

```
// Create a new scene
let scene = SCNScene()
var IBLImage = UIImage()
scene.lightingEnvironment.contents = IBLImage
```

But I want it to be able to rotate so that it can match with real environment. So far no luck with code in terms of rotating lighting Environment contents.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [contentsTransform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395388-contentstransform) instance property – a transformation that can be applied to the material property’s visual contents:

```
var contentsTransform: SCNMatrix4 { get set }
```

or

```
scene.lightingEnvironment.contentsTransform
```

> SceneKit applies **this transformation** to the texture coordinates provided by the geometry object the material is attached to, then uses the resulting coordinates to map the material property’s contents across the surface of the material.

About a representation of a 4x4 Matrix read [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmatrix4).

Also, read my answer about a **combination of shear and scale** (rotation) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362043/shear-matrix-as-a-combination-of-basic-transformation/52573589#52573589).

[image]

Comment: I noticed the same results, it seems like contentTransforms don't make a difference for `lightingEnvironment`.

Comment: this seems to have no effect on lightingEnvironment

Comment: @R.P.Carson, it's a funny thing: `scene.background.contentsTransform` is working but `scene.lightingEnvironment.contentsTransform` isn't...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, based on your explainition I created a function as follows

```
func makeRotationAroundY(angle: Float) -> simd_float4x4 {
 let rows = [
        simd_float4( cos(angle), Float(0.0), -sin(angle), Float(0.0)),
        simd_float4( Float(0.0), Float(1.0), Float(0.0), Float(0.0)),
        simd_float4( sin(angle), Float(0.0), cos(angle), Float(0.0)),
        simd_float4( Float(0.0), Float(0.0), Float(0.0), Float(1.0))
    ]
 return float4x4(rows: rows)
 }
```

and called

```
scene.lightingEnvironment.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4(makeRotationAroundY(angle: GLKMathDegreesToRadians(180)))
```

However, there seems to be no change when I see content on sphere node for example. I put any angle in there seems to reflect no change.